# Configuring a 2-node simulation in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, unetstack

I'd like to set up a network simulation in IntelliJ IDEA. To do this I'm trying configure the IDE to use the 2-node-network.groovy script included in the package. I can run the simulation script and access the modems through the web interface but some shell commands such as 'tell', 'host' etcetera will not work.

The steps I've taken so far:

1. Configure an environment variable in the IDE to point to the Unetstack home directory (unet_home=.../unet-3.0.0/)
2. Made a new run configuration in the IDE with code copied from the 2-node-network.groovy script but changed the home variable:

```
    import org.arl.fjage.RealTimePlatform

    def unet_home = System.getenv("unet_home");
    println(unet_home)

    println '''
    2-node network
    --------------
    Stack:
    Node A: tcp://localhost:1101, http://localhost:8081/
    Node B: tcp://localhost:1102, http://localhost:8082/
    '''

    platform = RealTimePlatform   // use real-time mode

    // run the simulation forever
    simulate {
        node 'A', location: [ 0.km, 0.km, -15.m], web: 8081, api: 1101, stack: "$unet_home/etc/setup"
        node 'B', location: [ 1.km, 0.km, -15.m], web: 8082, api: 1102, stack: "$unet_home/etc/setup"
    }
```

Web shell output:

```
> mac
<<< CSMA >>>

[org.arl.unet.mac.CSMAParam]
  maxBackoff = 30.0
  minBackoff = 0.5
  phy = phy
  reservationsPending = 0

[org.arl.unet.mac.MacParam]
  ackPayloadSize = 0
  channelBusy = false
  maxReservationDuration = 600.0
  recommendedReservationDuration = 15.0
  reservationPayloadSize = 0
> tell host('A'), "Hello"
Unknown method: host(...)
> tell
Unknown command or property: tell
>
```

Comment: Seems like the shell extensions are not loading. Check the log file to see if there are any exceptions or errors logged during the startup process?

Comment: I get the following warning/error after the simulation is started and, what seems to me, the agents are started:
WARNING|org.arl.fjage.shell.GroovyScriptEngine@46:error|Groovy script execution failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the shell startup process, the commands are loaded from `etc/fshrc.groovy` file. It seems that this file execution failed, probably because it could not be found.

The system property that is used by the initialization script for finding `etc` is `unet.home` (not `unet_home`). That is usually set in the `bin/unet` shell script from the environment variable `UNET_HOME` when starting up Java:

```
java -Dunet.home="$UNET_HOME" ...
```

If you use the shell script to run your simulation, you should set the environment variable `UNET_HOME` (case sensitive) to point to your `unet-3.0.0` folder, which contains the `etc/` folder. If you directly run `java` yourself, you should set the system property `unet.home` like shown above.

In your simulation script, you can check if this is correctly set:

```
println(System.getProperty('unet.home'))
```

to help you debug.

Comment: I added -Dunet.home=... to VM options under Run configurations and now it works. Thanks!